# Virtual worlds software allowing dynamically changes via REST API calls

Tags: modeling, vr

Not necessarily a gaming world, but to experience working/living environments: which free and open source software allows dynamic world modification per (REST) API calls?

Related to: [Free software and formats for Modelling in 3D for future VR use](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/52608/free-software-and-formats-for-modelling-in-3d-for-future-vr-use)